# Similar histograms after removing mean and dividing with std

Tags: time-series, mean, standard-deviation, histogram, similarities

I have four time-series, of a physical quantity (heat flux). When I remove the mean value from my data points Xn = X - mean(X) and divide them with the standard deviation Xn' = Xn/std(Xn) the histograms of all cases are almost the same. What does this imply? Each simulation has increasing input of energy and the magnitude of flux increases. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are your means about 0 and standard deviations about 1?

Comment: after removing the mean and dividing yes they are

Comment: What about before?

Comment: totally different. the first simulation has a mean almost ten times smaller in magnitude compared to the last one. Each simulation is done with increasing inputted energy.

Comment: When you say "the histograms are almost the same", presumably you mean the shape appears broadly the same but the axes are different. If the samples are large, this is not the least bit surprising, since subtracting a constant and dividing by a constant wouldn't be expected to change anything more than the axes (except as far as the bins would be slightly different, due to changed proximity to the round numbers typically used for the bin origin and width.

Comment: I plot all of them in the same plot and fall upon each other. There are differences at the tail of the distributions.

Answer (score -1):

This is a standard technique for normalizing distributions of data. It seems like this implies your data comes from the same family of distributions defined by the mean and std. dev. parameters.

Comment: that seems correct but what does it imply for the control parameter (energy) of the different simulation?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean -- it would seem that changing the control parameter doesn't affect the type of distribution, but only has some scaling effect on the parameters?

Comment: yes how can I find the scaling law?